# Does a lift to drag ratio of 100 imply an unattainable performance ratio of 1?

Tags: aircraft-performance

An answer to [this](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/96953/a-review-of-eta-efficiency-factor-for-propellers) question stated that a lift to drag **ratio** of 100 is "unachievable".

When thinking of *ratios*, they seem to always be a *fraction* of one thing to another, with the *sum* of them being the *total* amount of what is being compared.

For example a *ratio* of 1 to 4 means and apportionment of 1/5 and 4/5, 20% and 80%.

From [this](http://www.airfoiltools.com/airfoil/details?=dae21-il) reference we can see that the DAE 21 airfoil exceeds a lift to drag ratio of 100.

It seems that, as an efficiency, lift to drag ratio (or any ratio) can not be expressed as anything other than:

> fraction of a ratio = n/(n+1)

Yes, this can never equal 1.

Is this correct?

> "to what extent are we, as responsible persons, required to correct the misunderstandings?"

Just another day in the office at the Aviation Stack Exchange website.

Comment: What's a performance ratio?

Comment: @sophit it was the phrase "jets have constant thrust, props have constant power" that piqued my interest.  But props can have closer to constant thrust by adjusting their pitch to the freestream velocity (maintaining efficiency).  Jets solve the problem by having their fans churn happily away in a duct away from the free stream.  Ha!

Comment: @RobertDiGiovanni That's not how it works... Jets accelerate a small mass to very high speeds, giving them a low propulsive efficiency at low speeds (where a propeller would have a high efficiency). The fact that their efficiency is low at low speeds is why it doesn't decrease much at high speeds. Also, at those speeds where a propeller can no longer accelerate the air (which it must to produce thrust), a jet can, because as stated earlier, jets accelerate small mass to *very high speeds*. While this restrains the efficiency at low speeds, it allows the jet to produce thrust at high speeds.

Comment: "constant power can approximate constant thrust if blade AoA is kept optimal" - not true. If you look at the chart given in [this answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/96956/65631) of mine, you can see that for a constant power, thrust decreases as speed increases. That graph is derived from the relationship $P=V⋅T$
.

Comment: @AdityaSharma again many thanks for your comments.  My study of Isp shows that there is more than "mass flow" with jets.  Just look at the cross section of the turbine blades.  Something Bleriot would have been familiar with in 1909.  And I do not see the need to carry power through propulsion.  Force moves objects.  So once force is applied (from any propulsion system) only drag will stop acceleration.  The neat thing I learned is how important efficiency is.  Proper pitch to the relative wind is essential.

Comment: "carry power through propulsion" what does that mean?

Comment: It means that that whatever the propulsion system is acting on (the airframe) is being moved by force.  All the bells and whistles on the engine no longer matter.  If prop efficiency is maintained, the "push" on the airframe can keep it accelerating beyond where a fixed pitch loses efficiency.  This was a major improvement in aviation.  120 knots became 320 knots.  Reducing drag improved top speeds even more.

Comment: You can keep a factor between 0 and 1 and express an infinite range of ratios. 0.51:0.49 (1.04:1); 0.99:0.01 ; 0.999996:0.000004 (249,999:1); 0.99009901:0.00990099(100:1 or the smaller quantity as a fraction of the total is 1/101, although with L:D such a scaler fraction is meaningless because you would be interested in the vector components)

Comment: "Proportion" was the word I was searching for earlier.
A ratio can be zero. My ownership ratio of personal jets to cars is 0:1.  
The limits of a proportion are zero and one, as one side of the ratio approaches either zero or infinity with the other side held at any finite quantity. (calculus definition of limits)

Comment: @MaxPower 0 jets.  Well, have to start from somewhere ;-).  This originally grew out of the statement that a glide ratio of 100 was impossible, which has been corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Terms can get kind of sloppy here. If you are truly talking about the *ratio* of Lift to Drag, it would be best expressed as *a ratio of one number to another*. If someone talks about a Lift to Drag ratio of "100", what they *really* mean is a Lift to Drag *ratio* of 100:1. This means that Lift/Drag = 100/1 = 100. Nothing unattainable about that.

So could we say that out of 101 mysterious "somethings", 100 of them are "Lifts" and 1 of them is a "Drag"? Sure, maybe, but that doesn't seem like a terribly useful concept, since we are talking about two orthogonal forces.

As opposed to saying that the ratio of Cats to Dogs is 5:2, for example -- here the sum of 5 + 2 = 7 *would* have some useful relevance, i.e. the actual total number of animals present in a sample size that had 5 cats...

Your question mentions a *performance ratio*.  It's not clear what this would be mean.  Are you making the mistake of thinking that a L/D ratio of 100/1 (i.e. 100) somehow has something to do with *100 percent?*  That would be a misconception.

One can find sources on the internet ([example](https://www.mathswithmum.com/ratios-to-fractions/#)) that imply that when a ratio is converted to a fraction, the denominator should reflect the *total number of things present*.  In other words, in the Cats-and-Dogs example above, we can say that the "Cat fraction" is 5/9 and the "Dog fraction" is 2/9.  *But that's not what we mean we express an L:D ratio as a fraction.*  When we talk about "L/D", we simply mean Lift divided by Drag.  If L/D is 100, then that simply means that Lift is 100 times greater than Drag, so Lift/Drag = 100/1 = 100.

Are you thinking that a Lift/Drag ratio of 100 somehow implies that (following the phrasing of the previous paragraph) the "Lift Fraction" is 100% or 100 /100, meaning that (Lift / (Lift + Drag)) = 1, and thus implying that Drag is zero?  That would be a misconception.

Comment: I’d read the question as suggesting that 100:1 is a practical limit, which seems plausible given that the highest performing sailplanes were still a little way short of this last time I checked, and presumably if anyone knew how to make a higher-performing glider then they would.

Answer (score 2):

Lift to Drag, (L/D), is just a ratio, so it is perfectly possible to be greater than 1.

Comment: That’s the whole point of an aeroplane really, to you allow to remain airborne with less thrust than your weight.

Comment: $η$ is also just a ratio, but it's **impossible** for it to be greater than 1. Maybe you can explain why that's not the case with L/D.

Comment: @AdityaSharma, a ratio can be any value. Efficiency is a matter of "how much of it is (not) lost during the process". That's why it starts from 1 (perfect) and ends with 0 (wasteful). However, a ratio [0,1], is an ordinary arithmetic division.

Answer (score 2):

When people say that $L/D$ is a measure of aerodynamic efficiency -- they are using the word efficiency very loosely.  They are simply using it as a generic term for 'figure of merit'.

When people say that efficiency ($\eta=p_o/p_i$) can not be greater than 1.0, they are referring specifically to a precise definition of efficiency as the ratio of power out to power in.  Note that this engineering definition of efficiency does not apply to other quantities (mass, force, speed, time, money, etc.).

Usually this definition of efficiency is applied to power conversion and transmission devices.  Things like electric motors that convert electrical power to shaft power, propellers that convert shaft power to thrust power -- or wires and shafts that move power from one place to another.  These devices do not store energy.  They have an instantaneous state -- if power is going in, then power is coming out.

The fact that efficiency must be less than 1.0 is due to the laws of thermodynamics.  1) You can only break even ($\eta\le1.0$).  2) You can't even break even ($\eta<1.0$).

When we run a power conversion device 'backwards' (say using a motor in a generating mode, or using a propeller as a windmill), we must be careful to re-define what 'input' and 'output' means.  Losses like friction and resistance are always there of course.

For all of these devices, the 'inefficiency' ($1-\eta$) is a measure of the power lost to friction, resistance, drag, and other phenomena that eventually wind up as waste heat.  The first law tells us that $p_i=p_o+p_l$ -- the input power comes out as useful output plus losses.  This lets us write $\eta=p_o/(p_o+p_l)$.  Which (with $p_o$ and $p_l$ always positive) shows that $\eta$ must be less than 1.0.  T

We can also talk about efficiency of an energy storage device -- say a battery, flywheel, or spring.  Here again, we might use the symbol $\eta$, but we have to be extra careful.

First, we must make clear the energy we put in $e_i$, the energy stored $e_s$, and the energy we get out $e_o$.  When we put energy into a battery, we might think about a charge efficiency $\eta_c=e_s/e_i$.  When we draw energy from a battery, we might think about a discharge efficiency $\eta_d=e_o/e_s$.  Or, we might ignore the middle step and think about a round-trip efficiency $\eta_{rt}=e_o/e_i$.

This energy storage efficiency is not an instantaneous measure -- it takes time to charge or discharge a battery.  You might only partially charge (or discharge) a battery.

Energy is the integral of power over time $e=\int_{t_i}^{t_f}p\ dt$.  So energy storage efficiencies are integral measures of efficiency -- think of them as an averaging process.  As we charge a battery, any instantaneous transfer of power has some efficiency.  Over the complete charge, there is some average efficiency that reflects the energy (rather than the power).

This is just to say that we must be careful when working with efficiencies that we know exactly what definitions / conventions are being applied and what we can do with them.

Answer (score 2):

There's a bit of confusion here between **a** generic ratio and **the** ratio defining efficiency (or performance or figure of merit or whatever you want to the name it).

---

The ratio between two quantities is... well, the ratio between two quantities. If the forward chainring of a bike has 52 teeth and the chainring is engaged with a sprocket of 13 teeth, then their ratio is 1:4=0.25 (or 4:1=4). If I have five pens and my roof has 100 tiles, their ratio is 5:100=0.05 (or 100:5=20). If an airplane generates 4000N of lift and 500N of drag, their ratio is 4000:500=8.

---

Efficiency is the specific ratio of: (*one quantity we are interested in*) and (*the whole*). If 5 roof tiles are broken and 95 are good, the efficiency of my roof tiles is 95/100=0.95 (or the inefficiency is 5/100=0.05). The airplane of before generates a total aerodynamic force of $\sqrt{4000²+500²}=4031N$ and its efficiency in generating lift is therefore 4000/4031=0.992.

Note that being efficiency defined as (a part)/(the whole) then it is a number between 0 and 1. This implies that multiplying it by 100, we get efficiency in percentage.

Comment: We can move on, thanks.

Comment: @RobertDiGiovanni The point is not to just 'move on'.  You have have satisfied your understanding, but someone else who comes along later may have the same question and find this page -- or they might find it and become confused.  Please select a response as a correct answer to close out this question.  If no single response provided you with clarity, then answer your own question.  Once answered, we can all move on.

Comment: @RobMcDonald appreciate your response.  My question was more about a question where L/D was discussed.  I was simply clarifying L/D as a ratio of two quantities > 0, expressed as x : y, or a fraction of x/(x+y), but not anything that had a limit (mathematicly) or was generally used when one of the quantities was zero.  With our group efforts, I believe we can agree to L/D **ratio** of 100 is not an absolute limit.

Answer (score 1):

L/D is a ratio of forces, so it can be greater than 1. A reduction gear also produces more output force (torque) than input torque. It does so by trading rotation speed for torque. That's precisely what an aerofoil does - the only difference being that it does so aerodynamically instead of mechanically.

$Power = Force \cdot distance/time$

An aerofoil trades Speed for Force (lift force), thus giving it an L/D ratio greater than 1.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142400/discussion-on-answer-by-aditya-sharma-does-a-lift-to-drag-ratio-of-100-imply-an).

Answer (score 1):

But of course! Perhaps my view of this issue regards coming to terms with understanding the propeller thrust issue, and its relationship to the lift to drag ratio. Somebody asked 'what is performance ratio?'  Simply put, this is efficiency. How does one get 100 percent efficiency out of anything? The answer is only with great difficulty. But I digress...

With propeller thrust, we can do a lot of stuff. Going to the primordial equations, we find that if we know the power, velocity, and lift to drag ratio, we can determine the weight of the aircraft we can sustain in flight.  What's that, you may ask...

$$W = (L/D)*((lb \cdot ft/sec)/V)$$

Yes, interesting is how that equation resolves.  Now, as noted in the previously mentioned answer, we can re-define this equation algebraically to solve for anything else within the equation that we wish to know.  The only limitation is that we have to know the stuff on the right side of the equation. Specifically, the term in brackets, $(L/D)$, is the lift/drag ratio, is given properly in the equation by $C_L/C_D$.  We note, lb$\cdot$ft/sec is power, V is velocity in ft/sec.  The method for determining thrust has already been well sustained, elsewhere.  The performance ratio for the best propellers is about 88 to 89 percent.  In other words, the best propeller is about 88 to 89 percent efficient.  Consequently, propeller thrust is about 88 to 89 percent of rated power available to turn the propeller.  Assuming, of course, that the propeller is operating at its optimal speed and pitch relative to V.  An aircraft assessment invoking the above equation can be offered if necessary.

Comment: The "primordial equations".  Ah yes, those I am working on.  L/D.  Much better.  Thanks.

Comment: @RobertDiGiovanni  A small edit to provide proper perspective on the equation that was provided.  Note the addition.  The term in brackets, $(L/D)$ is given properly by $C_L/C_D$.  Both expressions, however, give the desired number, the lift/drag ratio.